# Creating a CacheManager from an XMLConfiguration using a StatisticsService

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-3

I know how to create a `CacheManager` using an `XMLConfiguration` in org.ehcache:ehcache:3.8.1:

```java
import org.ehcache.config.Configuration;
import org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder;
    .
    .
    .
    URL myUrl = CacheUtil.class.getResource("/my-config.xml");
    Configuration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(myUrl);
    cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(xmlConfig);
    cacheManager.init();
```

I also know how to create a `CacheManager` with a `StatisticsService`:

```java
StatisticsService statisticsService = new DefaultStatisticsService();
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
      .using(statisticsService)
      .build();
cacheManager.init();
```

But how do I create a `CacheManager` from an `XMLConfiguration` using a `StatisticsService`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor inside the class `EhcacheManager` that takes 2 arguments:

```
public EhcacheManager(Configuration config, Collection<Service> services)
```

You could use it as follows:

```
URL myUrl = CacheUtil.class.getResource("/my-config.xml");
Configuration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(myUrl);

StatisticsService statisticsService = new DefaultStatisticsService();
Set<Service> services = new HashSet<>();
services.add(statisticsService);

cacheManager = new EhcacheManager(xmlConfig, services);
```

Comment: Once you've set this up, how do you actually get run-time statistics?  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Try to call `getCacheStatistics` and `collectStatistics` on `statisticsService`: https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/ehcache/core/spi/service/StatisticsService.java https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/ehcache/core/statistics/CacheStatistics.java

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that demonstrates the usage of basic JCache configuration APIs:

```
 CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();  
CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();   
MutableConfiguration<Long, String> configuration =
    new MutableConfiguration<Long, String>()  
        .setTypes(Long.class, String.class)   
        .setStoreByValue(false)   
        .setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ONE_MINUTE));  
Cache<Long, String> cache = cacheManager.createCache("jCache", configuration); 
cache.put(1L, "one"); 
String value = cache.get(1L);
```

1. Retrieves the default `CachingProvider` implementation from the application’s classpath. This method will work if and only if there is only one JCache implementation jar in the classpath. If there are multiple providers in your classpath then use the fully qualified name `org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider` to retrieve the Ehcache caching provider. You can do this by using the `Caching.getCachingProvider(String)` static method instead.
2. Retrieve the default `CacheManager` instance using the provider.
3. Create a cache configuration using `MutableConfiguration`
4. with key type and value type as `Long` and `String` respectively…​
5. configured to store the cache entries by reference(not by value)…​
6. and with an expiry time of one minute defined for entries from the moment, they are created.
7. Using the cache manager, create a cache named `jCache` with the configuration created in step <3>
8. Put some data into the cache.
9. Retrieve the data from the same cache.